# Enviar ruta con imagen como parámetro desde vista a acción de controlador

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Solicito de la manera más atenta su apoyo en resolver este detalle para enviar un parámetro de archivo con ruta como valor a la acción de un controlador estamos trabajando con MVC 5 / C# / VS2019 / Bootstrap, el cual he intentado de algunas formas, pero siempre en la acción he obtenido null como valor.

Ahora bien este es mi código en el script para enviar la imagen:

```
  function appendImage(file, img_id, maxSizeWH = 3000) {
        function calculateAspectRatioFit(srcWidth, srcHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
            var ratio = [maxWidth / srcWidth, maxHeight / srcHeight];
            ratio = Math.min(ratio[0], ratio[1]);
            return { width: srcWidth * ratio, height: srcHeight * ratio };
        }
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);

            debugger;
        console.log('entro');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            @*//url: '@Url.Action("ExpedienteDigital", "Digitaliza")',*@
                url: '@Url.Action("ExpedienteDigital", "Digitaliza")' + '/' + img,
            //data: '{"base64file": "' + btoa(strin.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(img.Array))) },
            dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "multipart/form-data",
            //contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#GeneralSection').html(response.responseText);
},
            error: function (error) {
                $('#GeneralSection').html(error.responseText);
}
```

});

El código en la acción del controlador para recibir el archivo lo tengo así:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExpedienteDigital(HttpPostedFileBase f)
    {


                if (f != null)
                {
                    string archivo = (DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "-" + f.FileName).ToLower();
                    f.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/upload/" + archivo));
                }


        return PartialView("_ClasificaDocumentos");
    }
```

Como verán recibo el archivo en la acción HttpPostedFileBase en f pero se recibe en null, que estoy haciendo mal... les dejo imagen de como es cargada la imagen ya en una ruta, ahora pretendo enviarla a una acción de controlador para guardar la imagen en una ruta del servidor... pero antes no me ha sido posible enviar y recibir en la acción...

Muchas gracias por la ayuda...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]